# Recover data from /Android folder - Android 11

Tags: android-11

I have OnePlus8 Pro with Android 11. As you all know, with latest Android changes, now the WhatsApp media/documents/status data is put in /sdcard/Android/media/com.whatsapp.com

I uninstalled the app, and I dont know if I deleted it or uninstallation did, but I lost all the whatsapp media content. I later installed WhatsApp thinking I would get the media back but the folder is fresh with barely any data.

Is there any way to recover this data using ADB commands or some linux thing?

Comment: on stock android devices `/sdcard` is part of Internal Storage and therefore encrypted. once deleted, [FBE](https://github.com/TeamWin/android_device_oneplus_instantnoodle/blob/android-11/recovery.fstab#L11)(+[metadata](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/metadata#switching-on-metadata-encryption)) encrypted files aren't recoverable. But some media can be downloaded again (afaik last 4 weeks at least)

Comment: HI @alecxs, thanks for replying. The above post suggest that I dump `userdata` partition onto an image and then fetch data from there.

I tried to do this `cat: /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata: Permission denied` but getting permission error. My device is not rooted, could you please help me how to move forward. Again, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: the above post covers some links with exceptions such as `TRIM` `DISCARD` `ERASE` `F2FS` `FBE` where data recovery is impossible. furthermore it requires raw access (such as EDL or root)